# Passport-Local and Express Router Issue with Imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local, module.exports

I have an Express.js app with a Passport-local Auth, I'm tying to implement express router to my app since it's getting really hard to debug

This is an example of my main file (app.js)

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const passport = require('passport')
const testing = require('./routes/file')

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use('/router', testing)

const initializePassport = require('./passport-config');
initializePassport.initialize(passport);

app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    let user = data.key
    res.send(`Hi ${user}`)
})

app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))
  
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }

    res.redirect('/login')
}
  
function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}

app.listen(3000)
```

This is what my main file is like, this works perfectly fine
and just to make things clear, The function are to check if a user is authenticated or not, also my passport-config returns something called `data.key` which is basically the username of the user.

Now I've created a router here `app.use('/router', testing)` with the route as `/router` for testing purposes

Now this is my file.js that is being used by express

```js
const express = require('express'), router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Handle POST requests
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('/test', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    let user = data.key;
    res.send(`Hello ${user}, this is coming from the router`)
})

module.exports = router;
```

Now as expected when I open the site at localhost:3000/router/test it returns a undefined error for data.key since it's not imported and then when I comment that out the line causing the error then checkAuthenticated doesn't work, even when I'm not logged in I can get access to the page, now this is the problem, how do I fix it, I've gone through the entire express router docs I couldn't find luck there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not in the global scope you need to set it to global to be able to see it like:

```js
    GLOBAL.authFunction = function(){
    
    }
```

Suggestion:

1- make a module for auth name it authModule.

2- import the module auth check middleware where ever you want.

Comment: I don't understand could you give me an example, with the variables I used, and also all the files aren't in the same folder, the file structure is like router (folder) file.js (in routes folder) and all the other files are outside the routes folder